# Jenkins: add some text to the build summary

Tags: jenkins

For each build in jenkins there's a page with a short summary of what happened in that build.
In my setup this page contains the list of commit messages that were added in this build, the name of the user who started that build and a note from the git plugin about the commit SHA1 and the branch name.

Is there a way for a normal script that I run as a build step to add something to this page? Is there a plugin which allows this?
I want to add a line with an HTML link to where the user can download this build.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Description Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) to add a custom HTML description.

A quick example :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does it help?

UPDATE: here is the syntax for a Jenkins pipeline script

```
  currentBuild.description = "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Stackoverbuild build" + env.BUILD_ID + "</a>"
```

Comment: Do you have an example to do this in a Jenkins pipeline job (using Groovy syntax)?

Answer (score 4):

I used [Badge Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/badge/) ([GitHub Source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/badge-plugin/blob/master/README.md)) for something like this.
Example:

```
def summary1 = createSummary(icon:"notepad.png", text:"started Builds:<br>")
summary1.appendText("myBuild1: SUCCESS<br>", false)
summary1.appendText("myBuild2: UNSTABLE<br>", false)
```